# Using mysql, find a list of IDs that have 1 value but not another

Tags: mysql

[image]

In this table, each receipt_id has multiple status_codes. How can I pull a list of receipt_ids that have a status code of 'A', but not 'B'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by `receipt_id` and take only those groups having your conditions group-wise

```
select receipt_id
from your_table
group by receipt_id
having sum(status_code = 'A') > 0
   and sum(status_code = 'B') = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`, e.g.:

```
SELECT t.receipt_id
FROM table t
WHERE t.status_code = 'A'
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT receipt_id FROM table WHERE receipt_id = t.receipt_id AND status_code = 'B'
);
```